# UIImagePickerController image Scaling and maintain its quality

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Image Size captured using Camera return's image of size 720*960.

The captured Image is displayed in a UIImageView of 320*436, like this.

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,436.0)];
imgView.image=img;//Image received from camera.
[self.view addSubView:imgView];
```

This, works fine image 720*960 is scaled to 320*436 and displayed.

Now, from here actual problem starts. I have another image of size 72*72.  This image is overlapped with the image received from camera at some arbitrary coordinates.

`CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,72.0,72.0);`

I am not able to find a better way to handle scaling and applying a overlay of another Image, at the same time maintain its quality.
The image needs to be send to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to scale images:

```
-(UIImage*) imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: But, what advantage this code will have over imgView.image=img;//Image received from camera.